# ModuleNotFoundError: (already installed not working)

Tags: python, module, python-requests

I can't figure out why Python will not recognize the modules. The packages are apparently installed in my pipenv according to my pipfile as you can see below.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"
beautifulsoup4 = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

yet, when I enter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

in my .py file, I still get ModuleNotFoundError

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: found the pipenv command equivalent to `pip freeze` and this also shows I have `requests` installed. photo below
[image]

Comment: Are the modules actually installed? Try `pip freeze` to get the currently available modules

Comment: Did you check if the package is present in the virtual environment packages folder?

Comment: @PnkFlffyUncrn I am still fairly new to this. it is not listed when I do `pip freeze` but I installed it with `pipenv install requests` so I wouldnt expect to see it using `pip freeze` and `pipenv freeze` is not a command I guess.

Comment: `pip` is the program one uses to install python modules. Pipenv uses this to give you a streamlined production-ready environment.
I would recommend you get familiar first with python and pip (read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)) before using pipenv.
Try `pip freeze` in the console where you also do `pipenv install ...` to debug your current problems

Comment: I was able to use just pip install but would prefer to have the packages in my virtual environment. So I'm still open to any ideas why I was not able to `pipenv install beautifulsoup4` or `pipenv install requests`